# wp-admin-canonical URL sets incorrectly in wp-admin for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin, wpengine

I have one WordPress Blog, which is hosted on Wp-Engine. The URL to the site is `www.example.com/blogs`. Now When I access the admin side, it removes the `blog` part, and the admin screen is loaded with `www.example.com/wp-admin`. Now if I click on any admin link, it will be redirected to 404 page on the `www.example.com`. If I disable javascript, it is working fine and the `blogs` part is not removed. I am not adding any custom javascript to admin side, but I can see this JS there :

```
if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
            window.history.replaceState( null, null, document.getElementById( 'wp-admin-canonical' ).href + window.location.hash );
        }
```

just below

```
<link id="wp-admin-canonical" rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/wp-admin/theme-editor.php?file=assets%2Fjs%2Fadmin.js&amp;theme=cx">
```

I think this is causing the issue. Now If I add the following code :

```
if(strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "wp-admin") >= 0) {
 $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'www.example.com/blogs';
}
```

This fixes the admin side issues, but somehow it is breaking the front-end site and giving 404 for some individual posts.

In my staging environment, `wp-admin-canonical` is different, and it is the WPEngine URL hence the Javascript doesn't have an impact, and it is showing an error on the console. But the production, it is the original URL, and so it is replacing the URL.

It would be helpful if someone can let me know how this issue can be fixed. I have the site URL and home URL in the `wp-options` settings set to https://www.example.com/blogs

Comment: Have you tried resaving the permalink settings?

Comment: wordpress admin canonical url is broken

Answer (score 0):

The code you added to modify `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` might be causing conflicts with the WordPress core functionalities.

You may try the following:

**Clear Cache**

**Check .htaccess:** Ensure that your .htaccess file is not causing any URL rewriting issues.

**WordPress Settings Update:** Make sure that the "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" settings in the WordPress admin dashboard are set correctly to https://www.example.com/blogs. To do this, go to Settings > General and update the "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" fields.

Comment: All these are correct. Also `.htaccess` file doesn't have any effect on WpEgnine

Comment: Then try debugging using "Debug Mode" and try the plugin conflict test.